# Flutter Dart: TextEditingController wont work when i shift to another file

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to Dart, and coding in general. I have produced this code after watching tutorials on YouTube. For the most part, I have been able to troubleshoot most of my problems on my own, yet I cannot figure out my most recent errors. Here I made a TextEditingController on a page(Which worked fine BTW), and later I shifted to another page to make the code clean. But they stopped working.

```
import 'package:care_ls/model/userProfileModel.dart';
import 'package:care_ls/services/database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:care_ls/views/views.dart';
import 'package:care_ls/controllers/controllers.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  

return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          controller: profilePageTextControllers().fnameController,
          onChanged: (e)=> print(e),
          obscureText: false,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'First Name',
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xff2AA8A1),
                width: 1,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
              ),
            ),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xff272361),
                width: 1,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: profilePageTextControllers().lnameController,
          obscureText: false,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Second Name',
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xff2AA8A1),
                width: 1,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
              ),
            ),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xff272361),
                width: 1,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1,
        ),
        
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final userprofile = UserProfileModel(
                  firstName: profilePageTextControllers().fnameController.text.trim(),
                  lastName: profilePageTextControllers().lnameController.text.trim(),
                  );

              await Database.addProfile(userprofile);
              profilePageTextControllers().fnameController.clear();
              profilePageTextControllers().lnameController.clear();
             
              print('Data Sent');
            },
            child: Text('Done')),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => Get.to(HomePage()), child: Text('Back')),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Here is My controller that I move to another file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class profilePageTextControllers {

TextEditingController fnameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController lnameController = TextEditingController();

 }
```

Can anyone help me in understanding what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source of problem is you haven't learn about the `state` properly and then you're trying to build a project using a state management.

First, you need to learn about [Stateless vs Stateful widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive#stateful-and-stateless-widgets). Then, you need to learn [State Management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro)

Do not succumb to the `get` package mentally by using that package in every corner of your code.

---

Now, let's dissect your code.

When you are using the following code:

```
controller: profilePageTextControllers().fnameController,
```

You're creating a new `profilePageTextControllers` object then accessing it `fnameController` property.

Then your other code:

```
controller: profilePageTextControllers().lnameController,
```

is creating another `profilePageTextControllers` object.

So, you have 2 differents object now.

Then you creating another objects in your `onPressed` button:

```
final userprofile = UserProfileModel(
                  firstName: profilePageTextControllers().fnameController.text.trim(),
                  lastName: profilePageTextControllers().lnameController.text.trim(),
                  );
```

So, you're trying to access `fnameController` and `lnameController` from different objects used in the `TextFormField`.

You can fix your code logic by creating a `profilePageTextControllers` variable then use it in your `TextFormField`. Something like this:

```
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  var _controllers = profilePageTextControllers();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       body : SafeArea(
         child: Column(
            children: [

               TextFormField(
                 controller: _controllers.fnameController,
                 ...
               ),

               TextFormField(
                 controller: _controllers.lnameController,
                 ...
               ),


                // Use _controllers in button onPressed too.
            ]
         )
       )
     );
             
  }
}
```

Or for the better solution, you can follow @saiful-islam answer by using StatefulWidget.

Comment: Ya true. I don't have any formal training in programming. I am learning from Youtube and most of it I'm learning by mistakes. Thank you so much

Comment: @sandeeprana: Don't get discourages by mistakes. `Make mistakes. Learn from them. Move on`. I also don't have any formal training in programming, but we can learn it from a proper book. Try to learn from a good book or if you can, find a good mentor.

Answer (score 1):

You have a silly mistake in here. When you use `TextFormField` you should use a global form key to handle the form. Try this code snippet

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
 ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
final _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

TextEditingController fnameController = TextEditingController();

TextEditingController lnameController = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Form(
      key: _key,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: fnameController,
            onChanged: (e)=> print(e),
            obscureText: false,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'First Name',
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xff2AA8A1),
                  width: 1,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xff272361),
                  width: 1,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: lnameController,
            obscureText: false,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Second Name',
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xff2AA8A1),
                  width: 1,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xff272361),
                  width: 1,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1,
          ),

          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final userprofile = UserProfileModel(
                  firstName: fnameController.text.trim(),
                  lastName: lnameController.text.trim(),
                );

                await Database.addProfile(userprofile);
                fnameController.clear();
                lnameController.clear();

                print('Data Sent');
              },
              child: Text('Done')),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.to(HomePage()), child: Text('Back')),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```